# Python: Dynamically import module contents

Tags: python, import

I have lots of

```
from myproject.settings import param1
from myproject.settings import ...
```

scattered all over my project.

Upon startup, I would like to load different "settings" module according to env var (for example `export SETTINGS=myproject.settings2)`

I tried to put in the `myproject.__init__.py`
someting like

```
module_name =  os.environ['SETTINGS']
m=__import__(module_name)
settings = m
```

but it won't work.

```
from myproject.settings import *
ImportError: No module named settings
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a bogus 'fromlist' argument.

`mymodule = __import__(mod, fromlist=['a'])`

It's worked for me before in situations similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
settings = __import__(os.environ['SETTINGS'])
```

> but it won't work.

Why? Your approach is the right one. As example, Django does this the same way.

Comment: I don't know I do from myproject.settings import * and get ImportError: No module named settings

Comment: `__import__` imports the module, just access it by the variable you assigned it to; `settings.SOME_SETTING = True`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the absolute path of `myproject.settings` to `PYTHONPATH` like so:

`PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/myproject/settings/`
`export PYTHONPATH`

Now you could keep this in ~/.bashrc (assuming UNIX env). This way whenever you open a new terminal this path is added to PYTHONPATH. i.e. python interpretor would add this path to it's like of paths to look for while importing a module.

Now whichever path you are simply type `import settings` & since `myproject/settings` is present python would load settings file.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it worked.

Here is my folder structure:

```
src/
 app.py
 settings/
   __init__.py
   production.py
   sandbox.py
```

In `settings.__init__.py`, I wrote:

```
import os    
settings_module = os.environ.get('APP_SETTINGS')
if not settings_module:
    from .sandbox import *
else:
    exec('from {} import *'.format(settings_module))
```

If the var env was not set, imports the sandbox module. If was setting, imports the module dynamically.

Hope this helps